# WPF при промотке окна текстовые элементы размываются и мылят глаз

Tags: c#, wpf

Когда проматываешь окно программы, то текст размывается, пробовал ставить такие опции окна:

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
```

но это не помогает.

Comment: Возможно, [этот текст](https://habr.com/ru/post/216833/#part5) вам немного поможет.

Comment: да, помогло, пишу в ответ, что значительно исправило размытие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитав [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/216833/#part5), рекомендованную @VladD, попробовал следующий код

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
```

в результате, ситуация значительно изменилась в лучшую сторону